# Matrix of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, cross-product

For some context, I am learning about the cross product, and the matrix we used as an example was: 
$
\textbf{V} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{v_{1}} \\
\vec{v_{2}} \\
\vec{v_{3}} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
which I am told is a  3 x 3 matrix. But since these vectors are in 3 dimensions, wouldn't they also be column vectors? How do we get to a 3 x 3 square from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, it's just a matter of notation (check at the beginning of your notes/text): if $v^i=(v^1_i,v^2_i,v^3_i)$ (where I write $v_i$ to indicate the $i$-th vector and $v^j$ the component, following you notation -I eliminate the arrow to simplify it-), the matrix $V$ you obtain is 
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
v^1_1 & v^2_1 & v^3_1 \\
v^1_2 & v^2_2 & v^3_2 \\
v^1_3 & v^2_3 & v^3_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Otherwise you consider $V^T=[v_1, v_2,v_3]$, and then you list your vectors in column. Hope it help!